# Object Key Not rendering React Component using firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, components

I am trying to render component but it is not rendering.
I am using Objectkey to loop through firebase realtime database
IT IS SHOWING DATA IN CONSOLE BUT NOT RENDERING Component
help me out through it.

It is also showing some warning.

**Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.**

```
class UserPost extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="userpost">
    {firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("post")
      .on("value", snapshot => {
        Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map((item, i) => (
          <Post
            key={i}
            title={snapshot.val()[item].title}
            username="Edward"
            image={snapshot.val()[item].post_img}
            comment={
              Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
                data.comments[snapshot.val()[item].comments]
              ).length
            }
            likes={
              snapshot.val()[item].likes
                ? data.likes[snapshot.val()[item].likes].length
                : null
            }
          />
        ));
      })}
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Not sure if this approach will work as it might be trying to render the Firebase promise, rather than the data in the last part of the chain. But firstly, add in a return for your `.on` step, i.e. `return Object.keys...`. If it's still not working, make try saving the Firebase data into state, then rendering your `<Post/>`s from that data

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: It is also showing some warning like Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` method is not recommended for doing subscriptions. Prefer using React lifecycle methods (like `componentDidMount`) for this kind of code :

```
class UserPost extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child("post")
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      this.setState({ posts : snapshot.val()})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="userpost">
        {Object.keys(this.state.posts).map((item, i) => (
              <Post
                key={i}
                title={this.state.posts[item].title}
                username="Edward"
                image={this.state.posts[item].post_img}
                comment={
                  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
                    data.comments[this.state.posts[item].comments]
                  ).length
                }
                likes={
                  this.state.posts[item].likes
                    ? data.likes[this.state.posts[item].likes].length
                    : null
                }
              />
            ))}
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is right but sometimes it takes time to load data from firebase database